# A universal term for "educación básica y media"

Tags: translation, spanish

I'm writing my curriculum vitae in english, but attended school in Chile. In our education system we have "educación básica y media". Those are the first twelve years of formal education before the University. I'm struggling to find a good translation for this term. In particular I'm interested in finding a term that can be universally understandable, independent of the particular schooling system of different countries.

Comment: *Completed pre-University schooling*. (Though, I feel compelled to point out, no one is likely to care about that on a CV. It's considered pretty much table stakes for any employment, and so is assumed of all applicants. If I were proofing your CV, I'd recommend you strike it altogether.)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that employers only care about post-secondary education.

Comment: I know it is not important. But in my particular case I had reasons to include it in the spanish version of my curriculum. Now I'm translating it and I want both versions to be equal.

Comment: Try K-12, which is understood as kindergarten through the final year of high-school.

Comment: @Egox K-12 is exclusively used in the US.

Comment: Can we know which country you are writing for?  The terminology can change between US, UK, Australia, Canada, and others.  I can speak only to the US, where *primary school* is grades K-5 (usually ages 5 to 10) and *secondary school* is grades 6-12 (ages 11 to 18).

Comment: I'm looking for jobs in various countries, that's why I'm looking for an universal term.

Comment: @DanBron, it's many years since I interviewed new graduates for jobs, so things may have changed; but certainly at that time, unless the candidate had a first class degree, we were at least as interested in their A level results (public examination at 17-18) as in the class of their degree.

Comment: It may be better to simply state your highest level of school achievement using the form *equivalent to Year 12* or *equivalent to GCE A-Level*, etc, using the terminology of whichever country you're applying to. At this point, this is not strictly-speaking an English question, but one for [academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) if you're applying for a university position or [the workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) if you're applying for a job. (Note: I'm not active on those SE sites. Before posting, read their help pages to see if the question is on-topic there.)

Comment: Elhi (**El**ementary **Hi**gh) is a synonym for K-12.

Comment: @deadrat Is that really a thing? Interesting. Where is is used?

Comment: @deadrat I too am interested in the answer to Dan Bron's question.

Comment: @DanBron Yeah, it's a thing.  You can check acronym finders, Wikipedia, and random places from the google.  It's by far less popular than *K-12*, and it's my impression that it's the preferred term of art in the text-book publishing-educationist complex.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Those who can, do; those who can't, teach; and those who can't teach enroll (at least in the US) in the unholy congregation of textbook publishers, test makers, policy "reformers", teachers unions, and university "schools" of education.  I believe that *ELHI* is used more often in this circle of hell that I call *educationism*.  Disclaimer: I don't have stats to back that up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would recommend you write

> "Completed Primary and Secondary Education (12 years) in [name of city], Chile."

This will be clearly understood by any English speaker.

Answer (score 3):

From all the given options, "Pre-University Schooling" is the one I like the most because of its universality.

This was previously posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends on which English-speaking country you're looking to use the CV in, but in the UK we have Primary (7-10) and Secondary (11-15) which I guess should be sufficient elsewhere, unless somebody else can say different?  We also use Further Education to refer to the period between Secondary (or High) school and University (referred to as Higher Education).  This isn't compulsory, but obviously universities will require those qualifications in order to gain entry.

Comment: To illustrate the differences, in the US the period between age 15 and 17/18 is still compulsory, still referred to as Secondary, and leads directly to college (university).  Higher Education is a synonym for college.

Comment: In the U.S., there is a distinction between *primary* and *elementary* in most places, and *higher education* refers to any postsecondary degree-earning course, including baccalaureate programs.

Comment: @choster- What part of the US?  In my experience (lived in MI/PA/NY/OH) primary == elementary.

Comment: @cobaltduck Oops, yes I just edited my post :-)  For us Higher is also university.  I meant Further Education.  Looks like I need to go back and do those years again ;-)

Comment: @cobaltduck Where I grew up in 1980s Southern California, schools that called themselves *primary schools* were typically K-2 or K-3, whereas elementary schools were typically K-6, except for Catholic schools, which were K-8 (with 7-8 often separated as a *junior high school*). Sometimes, the term *primary school* was applied to the K-2 or K-3 division of an elementary school, a convention which [apparently](http://www.kirksville.k12.mo.us/vnews/display.v/SEC/Kirksville%20Primary%20School%7CK-2%20Information) still [exists](http://www.epiphanyglobalschool.org/page.cfm?p=529) in some places.

Comment: @cobaltduck Compulsory attendance laws vary by state.  The lowest age is 16/10th grade in Arizona and Wyoming.

Comment: This is wrong: 'We [in the UK] also use Further Education to refer to the period between Secondary (or High) school and University (referred to as Higher Education).' **_Higher_ Ed** once just meant degrees (inc. postgrad), but now signifies study _at degree-awarding institutions_ (broadly, universities). It is post-compulsory (personal choice, after leaving school), and delivers a range of undergraduate and postgrad qualifications. **_Further_ Ed** _**also**_ signifies _formal_, post-compulsory study, leading to qualifications (often professional) from institutions _other than_ universities.

Comment: This is also wrong: '[Further Ed] isn't compulsory, but obviously universities will require those qualifications in order to gain entry.' FE qualifications _can_ be accepted for HE (university) entrance instead of conventional senior school (A-level) certificates, typically on a case-by case basis -- e.g. for students from countries with markedly different school systems, or mature students who left school pre-A-level to begin careers and now wish to enter HE. FE is not a _conventional_ route to HE, however, and is not 'lower'. The two sectors run alongside each other, for different purposes.

Comment: Blimey, this is wrong as well: 'In the UK we have Primary (7-10) and Secondary (11-15).' In fact, UK full-time education is _compulsory_ from age 5 to 16. Pupils can be enrolled from age 4, and'reception' classes can start at 3. With occasional exceptions, 'Primary' education takes place from age 4 or 5 to 11 or 13, and 'Secondary' education occurs from 11 or 13 until at least 16, when pupils take GCSE exams (in most of the UK) and can then leave if they wish. If they stay, then they can proceed to A-level exams, typically taken at 18. (Regional differences apply, especially in Scotland.)

Comment: I originally planned to edit this answer, since it addresses broadly relevant ideas... but basically every part of it wrong in some fashion or other. There would be nothing left.

Comment: @CaptainCranium Only just noticed the comments sorry.  I was basically just trying to help somebody based on my own personal experience.  I didn't say compulsory education begins at 7.  The school I started at 7 was called Primary School.  The school I was in before that wasn't called Primary School.  After High School (at 15) I did A-levels in a Further Education college, which not everybody from school did, so it's optional.  Then I went to do my Higher Education at a uni.  Feel free to edit it, or don't.  Or remove it if you want.  Or you can correct my personal experience if it's easier.

Comment: Obviously I don't doubt your experience. Mine, too, was anomalous (started secondary ed. at age 10, and took some GCEs at age 14). I agree that OP might benefit from country-specific information, especially since the Chilean system has broad similarities, so I have simply summarised the real pattern [as outlined by the British Council](http://www.educationuk.org/global/articles/16-and-under-education-path/), and clarified the real activity of the HE and FE sectors, so that OP has institutional information rather than personal anecdote. I can't remove your answer: only you could do that.